# Update item in another list with Workflow

Tags: workflow

I have two lists, List A and List B, both have lookups linked to each other.

List A (Contacts):

| Contact | Case(lookup from list B-case) |

| Name1 |

| Name2 |

List B (Cases):

| Case | Contact(lookup from list A-contact) |

| Case1 |

| Case2 |

When in List A I add Case1 to Name1 item, I want Case1 to be updated with Name1 in List B.

and vice versa:

when in List B I add Name1 to Case1 item, I want Name1 to be updated with Case1 in List A.

I'm having difficulties understanding the Define Workflow Lookup dialog.

I can have two separate workflows, one for each list, doesn’t need to be in one.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds similar to Mark Rackleys linked lists, http://www.sharepointhillbilly.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=40.
Perhaps you can find inspiration there

If you are working towards a many to many relationship you might either use a proper database (if performance might be an issue) or use a 3rd list to map the relationship, as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164751/many-to-many-relation-list-in-sharepoint